# c++ undefined reference to constructors with inheritance g++

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr, undefined-reference

I have a really simple code about 3 classes (Add, Update, Remove) inheriting from another one (Request).

Those classes are instantiated in another one called interpreter, as shared_ptrs with make_shared. I build the whole project with CMake and `Interpreter` does not belong to the same shared library as `Request` and all.

Thing is, when I compile this on MacOS with g++ (which calls Clang), it works perfectly. Now when I try to export it on Unix with g++ (the real one), it throws this error during linking :

```
src/interpreter/libinterpreter_obj.so : undefined reference to 'request::Remove::Remove(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
src/interpreter/libinterpreter_obj.so : undefined reference to 'request::Add::Add(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
src/interpreter/libinterpreter_obj.so : undefined reference to 'request::Update::Update(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
```

The fact that Clang can compile and run and not g++ is linked to the option that I have for Clang only: `-undefined dynamic_lookup`  .

So the linker is trying to find those constructors in `libinterpreter_obj.so`, when it should find them in `librequest_obj.so`

Also, here you have a simple way to reproduce the issue (only Remove is included since the error is the same for the three classes) :

CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(ANALYSEUR_STX C CXX)

set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c++14")

find_package(Threads REQUIRED) #Technicaly needed for shared_ptr

include_directories(src/)

add_subdirectory(src/request)
add_subdirectory(src/interpreter)

set(ALL
  src/main.cc)

add_executable(main ${ALL})

target_link_libraries(main
  request_obj
  interpreter_obj
  ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

src/interpreter/interpreter.hh :

```
# pragma once
#include <string>

namespace interpreter
{
  class Interpreter
  {
    public:
      Interpreter();
      std::string request();

    private:
      std::string item_;
  };
}
```

src/interpreter/interpreter.cc :

```
#include <memory>
#include "interpreter/interpreter.hh"
#include "request/request.hh"
#include "request/remove.hh"

namespace interpreter
{
  Interpreter::Interpreter() {}

  std::string Interpreter::request()
  {
    std::shared_ptr<request::Request> rq;
    rq = std::make_shared<request::Remove>(item_);
    return (rq->gen_request());
  }
}
```

src/interpreter/CMakeLists.txt :

```
set(SRC
  interpreter.cc)

add_library(interpreter_obj SHARED ${SRC})
```

src/request/request.hh :

```
# pragma once
#include <string>

namespace request
{
  class Request
  {
    public:
      Request(std::string item);
      virtual ~Request() = default;
      virtual std::string gen_request() = 0;

    protected:
      std::string item_;
  };
}
```

src/request/request.cc :

```
#include "request.hh"

namespace request
{
  Request::Request(std::string item)
    : item_(item)
  {}
}
```

src/request/remove.hh :

```
# pragma once
#include "request/request.hh"

namespace request
{
  class Remove: public Request
  {
    public:
      Remove(std::string item);
      std::string gen_request() override;
  };
}
```

src/request/remove.cc :

```
#include "request/remove.hh"

namespace request
{
  Remove::Remove(std::string item)
    : Request(item)
  {}

  std::string Remove::gen_request() { return ("remove"); }
}
```

src/request/CMakeLists.txt :

```
set(SRC
  request.cc
  remove.cc)

add_library(request_obj SHARED ${SRC})
```

src/main.cc :

```
#include "interpreter/interpreter.hh"

int main()
{
  interpreter::Interpreter itp;
}
```

To compile :

```
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake ..
make
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: If you are combining your code with some existing library, you may have got a mix of C++11 and pre-C++11 ABIs. If so you may need to either add or remove `-std=c++11` flag to your CXXFLAGS. Otherwise please make and post a [mcve] (sources, headers, makefiles, everything).

Comment: What is request? You don't show the implementation of Remove::Remove.

Comment: According to that linker error, "libinterpreter_obj.so" is the reason the linker started looking for those constructors, because some code in it attempts to use them; not that the linker was looking just there to find them. But the linker didn't manage to find them in any of its inputs at all. So did you in fact define them? Where?

Comment: @manni66 Request is the (virtual) base class for Remove, Update and Add. As for Remove's implementation (and Update and Add), the constructors only call the Request's one.

Comment: @aschepler libinterpreter_obj is a lib that I create. And those constructors are defined in another lib (librequest_obj) that I also create.

Comment: @n.m. So I was compiling with c++14. I tried with and without c++11, and no results whatsoever

Comment: Remove, Add and Update constructors are missing. Are they defined anywhere? **Show the definition**. Are they compiled? **Show the compilation command**. Are they linked to the final executable? **Show the link command**.

Comment: Yes, Request is the base (why do you think it's virtual?). But what is request in `request::Remove::Remove`?

Comment: Ok so I updated the whole thing so that you have a simple way to reproduce the error.
Also, @manni66 request is the namespace